# Adding copy task as dependency to existing Gradle task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a Groovy app that has the following directory structure:

```
build.gradle
gradle.properties
settings.gradle
src/
    main/
        groovy/
            <Groovy code>
        resources/
            config.json
    test/
```

Currently, when I run `gradle clean build shadowJar` (uses the [ShadowJar plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) **although I don't think thats relevant here**) I am left with a compiled, executable JAR located inside of `build/distributions`. I would like to add a task to my Gradle file that also copies the `src/main/resources/config.json` file to this `build/distributions` location, ideally without having to change my build invocation.

I tried this:

```
task copyJson(type: Copy) {
    from('src/main/resources')
    into('build/distributions')
    include('config.json')
}
```

However this forces me to use the following build invocation: `gradle clean build shadowJar copyJson`, which is not what I want.

So I ask: how can I add a task to my Gradle build such that running `gradle clean build shadowJar` not only produces my executable JAR under `build/distributions`, but also copies the `src/main/resources/config.json` file to that location as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
build.dependsOn copyJson
```

to your build.gradle file. Note that if build should always create the shadow jar, you could also add

```
build.dependsOn shadowJar
```

and build with `gradle build`.